# recursively enumerable sets closed under concatenation

Tags: computer-science, computability

I'm trying to show the set of all recursively enumerable sets is closed under concatenation. I'm trying to use the definition of recursively enumerable sets to construct the argument. I believe that I must  consider the Cartesian product $S_1\times S_2$ of two recursively enumerable sets $S_1$ and $S_2$. I then construct the function $f:S_1\times S_2\rightarrow \lbrace 1\rbrace\cup\lbrace\perp \rbrace$ (where $\perp$ is undefined) such that: $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
 1 &\text{  if } x\in S_1 \text{ and } y\in S_2\\
 \perp&\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Does the mere existence of this function $f$ show that $S_1S_2$ is recursively enumerable?
I'm still new to these proofs, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for pointing that out. I am thinking of the sets as encodings of integers

Comment: I just realized it doesn't matter that much and I was just about to edit my comment, but 5 mins were up. I'll delete it and repost:

Comment: Yes, it suffices to prove that $f'$ exists, because a set is r.e. iff it's the domain of a partial recursive function. // P.S. Why bother putting a prime on the function? There's no $f$ anywhere in sight to distinguish it from; just use $f$.

Comment: "I am thinking of the sets as encodings of integers" -- I'll assume you mean, "thinking of the sets as containing integers which encode sequences of integers", also known as 'sequence numbers'. Do you already 'know' that concatenation of sequence numbers is recursive? (as a binary function). It's safe to assume that the encoding is 'nice' in the sense that every int is a sequence number.